# Disabling animation of panel changes in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I just installed latest release of `RStudio` (`1.1.456` from July 2018).  It has a (nice I guess?) change to the panels behavior: when selecting `Editor` via `Option-1` it focuses on that panel and hides the `Console`.

Two things:

- The hiding is actually a relatively slow animation.
- I might actually *want* to see the `Console` at the same time as the `Editor`

So  ..

- is it possible to disable animation -i.e. show the current/active panel immediately ?
- is it possible to tell the IDE to continue showing both Panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened up a solution to the *second* question: to retain visibility of other panels when editing hit `Option-1` *twice* - and likewise for `Option-2` when working in the `console`